# Save drawing on screen android

Tags: android, save, drawing, screen, restore

I have an android app which is drawing lines when the user is touching the screen. All the points coordinates are stored in a LinkedList. How can i save the lines on the screen after the screen rotation?

Answer (score 0):

when screen has any change (rotation, resize...), your drawing region will change. and we have new coordinate.
so I suggest that you should clear and redraw all on new coordinate. It may be simple than saving the lines as views and redraw that views.